# Kafka console-producer to read result of console-consumer on the fly in bash

Tags: linux, bash, apache-kafka

I am consuming messages from kafka using console-consumer. I want to redirect the output of this console-consumer to consoler-producer. Using this I would be able to avoid using too much disk for consumed messages and I certainly can avoid duplication.

I have used `./consumer < <(producer)` but it seems NOT working.

Also the regular pipe `|` operator seems not functional.

Comment: Please clarify what is not working with a pipe. It has worked for me before. However, I use `kcat` now instead

Comment: It is working for me, too. | is naturally the first redirection operator there, thanks for mentioning it again.

Comment: You said "seems not functional", so edit your question to clarify that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up a consumer/producer pair to redirect consumer output from `topic-a` to a producer that produces to `topic-b`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

${KAFKA_HOME}/kafka-console-consumer.sh \
  --bootstrap-server localhost:29092 \
  --topic topic-a --from-beginning | \
  ${KAFKA_HOME}/kafka-console-producer.sh \
    --bootstrap-server localhost:29092 \
    --topic topic-b
```

(note: `$KAFKA_HOME` is just an environment variable to reference my Kafka `bin` folder)

I then set up another producer that produces to `topic-a`. Each message I sent to `topic-a` from this producer was replicated to `topic-b`.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

> redirect the output of [consumer topic] to [producer topic]

This is what MirrorMaker is for.

https://github.com/apache/kafka/tree/trunk/connect/mirror

Otherwise, Kafka Streams app can be used for the same, within the same cluster.

> Using this I would be able to avoid using too much disk for consumed messages

`kafka-console-consumer` does not write to disk. It writes to stdout.  The Kafka topic data still exists on the broker's disks.

> avoid duplication

Not really? `kafka-console-producer` doesn't dedupe data on its input stream.